# Facebook's mobile open graph

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I've recently heard that you don't have to create webpages for opengraph objects anymore and just post them from iOS app directly.
Having said that i've configured my Facebook app to be enabled for iOS only, but when i try posting OG object like that i get error:

```
NSMutableDictionary<FBOpenGraphObject> *object =
    [FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPostWithType:@"designdailyapp:item"
                                            title:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ by %@", [currentObject objectForKey:@"Title"], [currentObject objectForKey:@"Designer"]]
                                            image:@"https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png"
                                              url:@"http://designdaily.me/site.html?id=111"
                                      description:[currentObject objectForKey:@"Description"]];

    [FBRequestConnection startForPostOpenGraphObject:object completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        NSString* resultID = [result objectForKey:@"id"];
        //THIS IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR
        if (!error) {

        }
    }];
```

This is the error i'm getting.

> Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0xc0a3ae0 {com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=400, com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
>       body =     {
>           error =         {
>               code = 100;
>               message = "(#100) Object Base Domain Not Allowed: Object at URL 'http://designdaily.me/site.html?id=111' of type 'designdailyapp:item' is invalid because the domain 'designdaily.me' is not allowed for the specified application id '477605465664930'. You can verify your configured 'App Domain' at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/477605465664930.";
>               type = OAuthException;
>           };
>       };
>       code = 400;
>   }, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=, expirationDate: 2013-12-08 15:28:35 +0000, refreshDate: 2013-10-09 15:28:35 +0000, attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(
>       "user_friends",
>       installed,
>       "basic_info",
>       email,
>       "publish_actions"
>   )>}

I can get around it by configuring my Facebook app to also enable 'Website with Facebook login' and filling in domain field, but then i get rejected by not having a web site with Facebook login. 
Anyone got mobile open graph to work?

thanks in advance!

Comment: You can simply remove the 'url' property from your open graph object.

Comment: yeah but then what's the point of OG? How can i redirect users to my site?

Comment: If you have a website, then you should set up an App Domain and implement Facebook Login as appropriate.

Comment: But the site i have does not implement login with facebook, it's just a companion site like Instagram - just shows a photo and Available in AppStore button..